# Are Android thread id's global per process?

Tags: android

When you do a `Thread.currentThread().getId()`, is the resulting thread id scoped per process or scoped to the current Activity/Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's per-process.  The VM has no understanding of activities and services.